# × TypeError: navData.navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function v4x

Tags: react-native

I am following a react native course. I am trying to create an iconName = "ios-menu" but when trying to open it it does not work and it tells me that "TypeError: navData.navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function" I can't find a solution I would like to know why this happens somebody could help me.

```
enter code here

import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummy-data';
import HeaderButton from'../components/HeaderButton';
import CategoryGridTile from '../components/CategoryGridTile';
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

const CategoriesScreen = props => {
  const renderGridItem = itemData => {
    return (
      <CategoryGridTile
        title={itemData.item.title}
        color={itemData.item.color}
        onSelect={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate({
            routeName: 'CategoryMeals',
            params: {
              categoryId: itemData.item.id
            }
          });
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      data={CATEGORIES}
      renderItem={renderGridItem}
      numColumns={2}
    />
  );
};

CategoriesScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
  return {
    headerTitle: 'Meal Categories',
    headerLeft: (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title="Menu"
          iconName="ios-menu"
          onPress={() => {
            navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    )
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your DrawerNavigator.js when you create it, Probably you didn't export the module correctly at export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator "not stack but drawer");

Probably the reason why the toggleDrawer() function wasn't recognised as the react-navigation-drawer methods wasn't passed to App.js